# java, class not found exception com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

[image]

I am trying to create the run the following in java program, but i am getting this error.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

```
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

in build path, i have added the mysql connector jar file

Comment: Can you show your .classpath code whether the lib is pointing or not

Comment: As we can see in your screenshot, you have added it to the lib folder, but not to the classpath

Comment: @murthy can you tell me, where can i find the .classpath code

Comment: ... i think you should do tutorials for programming beginners first - theres no use in trying to do programming without proper knowledge about the subject, you will only fail if you do it

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, right-click on the project and select Build Path -> Configure Build Path.  Select the Libraries tab, then the Add Jars button.  Then select the MySQL jar file as shown in your project.  Then press OK then OK.  It should now work.

Comment: thats what i did initially, but is not working. as @Errabi said its working